# PowerShell scheduled task not converting CSV to EXCEL

Tags: powershell, automation, excel-2010, scheduled-tasks, windows-7-x64

I have a server health check script which i'm trying to get working by scheduled task.

The scheduled task has the following set for 'AddArguments"

```
Add Arguments: -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\HealthCheck.ps1"
```

Everything in the server health portion of full script works fine to create the .csv report, except the last part, which does the CSV to excel conversion/save/close - I've not included the preceding code as it includes some confidential stuff, and i don't believe it's relevant.

When I run the script with the same ID, but from the GUI (not as a scheduled task) it works fine.

Note: The last part of the script definitely does launch excel briefly and performs the functions, and saves/closes it - i'm thinking the scheduled task isn't doing this because it's not supported by Microsoft?

I did find the following [SpiceWorks post](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/358895-powershell-not-outputting-file-as-scheduled-task) but the solution noted didn't resolve the issue for me in this case. That's where you create a DESKTOP folder under these paths depending on your version of Office (i'm using Office 2010 32-bit on Windows 7 x64 Pro)

```
C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile 
C:\windows\syswow64\config\systemprofile
```

Anyway, here's the code - Any help appreciated!

```
#Convert CSV to EXCEL, format, and save
#Create excel object
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl.visible = $true

#Input
$Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open(“$Dir\Reports\SeverHealth-Results-    $CurrentDate.csv”)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
$xl.Rows.Item("2:2").Select()
$xl.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = $true
$HeaderRow = $Worksheet.Range("A1:L1")
$HeaderRow.Font.Bold = $True
$HeaderRow.Font.Underline = $True

$range = $worksheet.UsedRange
$range.AutoFilter() | Out-Null
$range.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
$rowc = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$colc = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

#Coloring
for ($z = 1; $z -le $rowc; $z++) {
$ActionReqCol = $worksheet.cells.item($z,7)
$ServerCol= $worksheet.cells.item($z,1)
if ($ActionReqCol.text -eq "YES") {
    $ActionReqCol.interior.colorindex=3
    $ACtionReqCol.font.colorindex=2
$ServerCol.interior.colorindex=3
$ServerCol.font.colorindex=2}}

#Save and close!
$EndDate = Get-Date
$EndDate = $EndDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hhmm')
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
$Workbook.SaveAs($Dir + "\Reports\SeverHealth-Results-$EndDate.xls”,     $XLFixedFormat)
$Workbook.Saved = $True
$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Doesn't sounds like a coding problem. Can you run powershell.exe with the same arguments in CMD? would you have the same problem? If yes, please share the error, if not, please share your scheduled task configuration.

Comment: It's odd for sure, works fine from a CMD line, just not via the scheduled task. The scheduled task is configured to run with the same account as well. The Add Arguments on the scheduled task are as follows: -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\HealthCheck.ps1

Answer (score 0):

Write the command to invoke the PowerShell with arguments in a batch file. I believe from the comments that you are already able to do this successfully. Configure the Task Scheduler to execute the batch file.

Other advantage of this is, you have reduced dependency. If later you want to make modifications to your command or alter arguments, then you will be able to do so without altering or even opening the Task Scheduler.

**Update:** @Kenny reported that running task scheduler's task with highest privilege resolved this. The script required elevated access and the same was provided by checking the check box in Task Scheduler to run the task with highest privilege.

Comment: Ok. Tried that today, but that didn't work either. I'm sure it's got to be related to the fact that Office requires the GUI to be opened/closed, this may be a limitation of running from a scheduled task, which wouldn't normally display anything to the screen.

Comment: @Kenny In that case, that is definitely your issue. The task you are trying to schedule you should be able to execute it non-interactively and in fully automated fashion. You should try to solve that first.

Comment: Update: Fixed. 
I had to set the scheduled task to "run with highest privileges" , that along with creating these two folders resolved the issue.

C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile 
C:\windows\syswow64\config\systemprofile

Comment: Thanks for the update @Kenny. I appreciate this. I have updated my answer with your update. If you see value and want you can up vote & mark this as answer for anyone else coming to this question, by click on up arrow and tick mark sign beside my response.